# dynamically replace EditText in TextInputLayout with another EditText

Tags: android, android-view, android-textinputlayout

I'm using TextInputLayout to show some input, somewhere in my code I want to replace the EditText with another EditText but when I do this design of the input gets messy. My code looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/generalInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
    android:theme="@style/InputLayoutStyle"
    style="@style/InputLayoutStyle"
    android:background="@drawable/input_border"
    >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/oldEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="شماره موبایل"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And I use this code to replace the edit text

```
    val parentOfEditText = oldEditText.parent as ViewGroup
    val index = parentOfEditText.indexOfChild(oldEditText)
    layoutParams = oldEditText.layoutParams
    parentOfEditText.removeView(oldEditText)
    inputET.layoutParams = layoutParams
    parentOfEditText.addView(inputET, index)
```

The result looks like this. the bottom input is how it should be (before replace) and the top one is after replace. But I can't figure out why this happens. BTW the exact the same view is used for replacing so the edit text is not changing.

[image]

Comment: can't you just change the text of the edit text for your condition ?

Comment: @VivekMishra  This is not about the text, lots of properties of the edit text is going to be changed. I have like 10 version of the edit text in separate files that I want to dynamically choose from.